# If i add multiple class to multiple articles can i access article using class name as keyword

Tags: html, css

language used:Html css

If i use multiple class to article like[class name] `one` `two` and `three` to xarticle, `two` and `three` for yarticle and `three` for zarticle.

Now can i display articles with class name `two`, in this case xarticle and yarticle.

Thanks in advance.

```
body{
<p class="one" class="two" class="three">how</p>
<p class="two" class="three">you</p>
<p class="three">doing</p>
}
```

in the above case can i display 'how you', by using class name two.

Comment: Please add some more info in the question... language used?

Comment: I am using Html and css.

Comment: What you posted isn't valid HTML or CSS. It starts out as CSS, then switches to HTML, then switches back to CSS.

Comment: When you repeat the attribute name the previous value gets zapped. Do `<p class="one two three">` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use multiple `class` attributes, but you can put multiple classes in the same attribute:

```
<p class="one two three">how</p>
<p class="two three">you</p>
<p class="three">doing</p>
```

To display only the articles with the class `two`, you hide all articles, and override it for that class. Place the following code in your CSS.

```
p { display: none; }
p.two { display: block; }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L2A92/)**

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   <p class="one two three">how</p>
   <p class="two three">you</p>
   <p class="three">doing</p>
```

***CSS***

```
p { display: none; }
p.two { display: block; }
```